# sybase dbunload usage leads to 'authentication violation'

Tags: authentication, sybase, sqlanywhere

all! I have a db and want to unload it and reload it into the same file.
I use `Sybase Anywhere 16` utility `dbunload.exe`. the command is:

```
dbunload.exe -c "UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBF=mydb.db" -ar .
```

the utility starts its work and the output is:

```
SQL Anywhere Unload Utility Version 16.0.0.1915
Connecting and initializing
Unloading user and group definitions
Unloading spatial units of measure
Unloading spatial reference systems
Unloading sequences
Unloading table definitions
Unloading text configurations
Unloading materialized view definitions
Unloading index definitions
Unloading functions
Unloading view definitions
Unloading procedures
Unloading triggers
Unloading SQL Remote definitions
Unloading MobiLink definitions
Creating new database
***** SQL error: Authentication violation
```

The question is: how to force dbunload to load db back?

PS: I have 2 db's - one for sybase 11 and another one for sybase 16. dbunload from sybase 11's installation works well for 11's db. but for 16's db version I have the problem described above.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that Sybase installation is not developers one. therefore http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbadmin/dboptions-s-4985733.html

```
This option only takes effect when you are using the OEM Edition of the SQL Anywhere database server.
To authenticate a database, set the database_authentication option for the database:

Example:
SET OPTION PUBLIC.database_authentication =
 'company = company-name;
 application = application-name;
 signature = database-signature';
```